# c# delegate -> typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, delegates, cocoscreator

c# code

```
enum myEnum
{
    aa = 0,
    bb,
    cc,
}

public delegate void MyDelegate(myEnum _myEnum, params object[] _params);

public Dectionary<myEnum , MyDelegate> dicMyDelegate = new Dectionary<myEnum , MyDelegate>();

public void GameDelegate(myEnum _myEnum, MyDelegate _Func)
{
    if(dicMyDelegate .ContainsKey(_myEnum))
    {
        MyDelegate Func;
        dicMyDelegate.TryGetValue(_myEnum, out Func);
        Func += _Func;
    }
    else
    {
        dicMyDelegate.Add(_myEnum, _Func);
    }
}

public void GameCallBack(myEnum _myEnum)
{
    if(!dicMyDelegate.ContainsKey(_myEnum)) return;
    MyDelegate Func;
    dicMyDelegate.TryGetValue(_myEnum, out Funk);
    if(Func == null) return;
    Func(_myEnum);
}
```

==================================================

cocos creator TypeScript. i don't know.... plz. i'm now study.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(myEnum _myEnum, params object[] _params);

public Dectionary<myEnum , MyDelegate> dicMyDelegate = new Dectionary<myEnum , MyDelegate>();
```

It is difficult to replace the above code with a type script.

I am searching the internet all day.

```
declare module "Delegate"
{   
    export function MyDelegate(_myEnum: myEnum , args: any[]) : void;
}

import {MyDelegate} from 'Delegate';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript and TypeScript, functions are first class citizens, so you don't need to solve the problem in the same you do in C#.

```
function example(name: string) : string {
    return 'Hello ' + name;
}

function acceptsFunction(func: Function) {
    // Calling the function that was passed as an argument
    const result = func('Steve');
    console.log(result);
}

// Calling a function, passing another function as an argument
acceptsFunction(example);
```

In the example above, you can pass the function as an argument, and call it with arguments - all with no additional complication.

You can improve type safety by specifying what *kind* of function must be passed:

```
function acceptsFunction(func: (name: string) => string) {
```